# Computer Component with Gamma Distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I comes to a question of one old-exam as follows:

if the life of one computer component (in year) has `Gamma Distribution` (if I translate correctly) with `mean = 6` and `variance 18`, How we can find the probability that this component has at least `9` years life?

What is the method of solving such question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The gamma distribution is usually determined by two parameters, namely the shape parameter $k$ and the scale parameter $\theta$ (following [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)). Let me outline how I would do it.

What you need is to translate your information about the mean and variance into information about the parameters $(k,\theta)$. But this can be done, since both the mean and variance are expressible in terms of $k$ and $\theta$ as follows:

$$\text{mean} = k\theta,$$
$$\text{variance} = k\theta^2.$$

Plugging in the given mean and variance, you thus need to solve the following two equations with two unkowns for $k$ and $\theta$:

$$6 = k\theta,$$
$$18 = k\theta^2.$$

You also have that the density $f(x)=f(x;k,\theta)$ of the gamma distribution is given by

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}.$$

You can plug in the values of $k$ and $\theta$ from above. If you let $X$ denote the lifetime of the computer component, then you want to calculate the probability that $X$ is at least $9$, that is, you want to calculate $P(X\geq 9)$. In terms of the density, this probability is given by:

$$P(X\geq 9) = \int_9^{\infty} f(x)\ \text{d}x = \int_9^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}\ \text{d}x.$$

I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: My book solved it as $4e^{-3}$

Comment: Yeah? And what do you get, when you calculate the integral I posted?

Comment: my problem exactly via your integral, would you please numerically solve it to learn me ?

Comment: I will help you solve it analytically, yes. First, what do you get for $k$ and $\theta$, when you solve the two equations I listed?

Comment: 2,3 ?  am i right /

Comment: I agree, $k=2$ and $\theta=3$. :) What happens with the density/thing you want to integrate, when you plug in these values? I mean, how does it look like?

Comment: I have no idea for this :)

Comment: It's straightforward. Just plug in $k=2$ and $\theta=3$ in the expression $f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time,  would you please show me. I confused :)

Comment: Ok, so I have the expression $f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)\theta^k}x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$. This is what I want to integrate. Notice the $k$ and the $\theta$ in this expression? I just substitute $k=2$ and $\theta=3$ for these, and I get $\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)3^2}x^{2-1}e^{-\frac{x}{3}}$. I can simplify this as $\frac{1}{\Gamma(2)9}xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}$. Also, you may know how the gamma function $\Gamma$ behaves on integers. In fact, $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$, when $n\geq 1$ is an integer. In particular, $\Gamma(2) = 1!=1$, so the expression reduces to $\frac{1}{9}xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}$.

Comment: Confusing !! last result is $4e^{-3} $ my prof. says.

Comment: Yeah, it's because you haven't done the integral yet. You have to find $\int_9^{\infty}\frac{1}{9}xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}\ \text{d}x$. This will turn out to be $4e^{-3}$.

Comment: I know waste your time. but please help me. would you please complete your answer to numerically reach to my answer? comment is so confusing...

Comment: I would like to help you, but I also want you to learn something. To solve the integral, you can do integration by parts. The general formula for this is $\int f(x)g(x)\ dx = F(x)g(x) - \int F(x)g'(x)\ dx$, where $F$ is an anti-derivative/primitive of $f$, and $g'$ is the derivative of $g$. In your case, let $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x}{3}}$, and let $g(x) = \frac{1}{9}x$. Then $\int f(x)g(x)\ dx = \int \frac{1}{9}xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}\ dx$ is exactly the integral you want to find. So use the formula for integration by parts. What is $g'(x)$? What is $F(x)$?

Comment: You are so kind. I have nothing to say from your valuable comment. I try to learn by example. +1 and accept. I learn it when see a full example. if you prefer please complete your answer. thanks so much.

Comment: @kos.ir you can also check out what wolfram alpha has to say about the integral: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int_9^{\infty}\frac{1}{9}xe^{-\frac{x}{3}}dx Note how it exactly gives you the professor's answer

Comment: wrong link? it's not possible to complete it here?

Comment: My challenge is still remains. would you please complete it?

Comment: my confusing is still continue. please complete it. thanks